# How can i user refs in stateless functions React-Native, am using React-Native 0.62.2

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an input called CodeInput from styles using `styled/components` and I want to create multiple inputs from a map but I get a warning Functional components can not be given refs, Attempts to access ref will fail.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

import {CodeInput} from './styles'

const codeInputs = (props) => {
    const inputFields = useRef([])
    const submitClick = index => {
        console.log("ref #: " + inputFields.current);
      };
    return (
        <CodeInput onChange={submitClick} keyboardType="phone-pad" maxLength={1} ref={el => {inputFields[index] = el }} />
    )
}
```

and here below I use the above component to create multiple inputs

```
const renderInputs = () => {
      const array = new Array(4).fill(0)
       return array.map((_, idx)=>(
           <CodeInputs index={idx} key={idx}/>
       ))
 }
```

Comment: Use `createRef` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
const codeInputs = ({index}) => {
const inputFields = [];
const submitClick = index => {
    console.log("ref #: " + inputFields[index]);
  };
return (
    <CodeInput onChange={() => submitClick(index)} keyboardType="phone-pad" maxLength={1} ref={el => {inputFields[index] = el }} />
)
}
```

Comment: Please share a codesandbox link here, That would be easier to understand the issue.
Also please make sure you've checked my solution properly. I've not only used array, i've also changed some small things in many places